# Get post info inside modal window?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, wp-query

**What I'm Trying To Do**

I have set up a custom post type for 'movies' and below is how I set up the template. Basically, I am trying to get `a.thickbox` (in the code below) to open a modal window with more info on the movie. Notice the addition of `&pid=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>` at the end of the `href`.

```
<?php get_header();?>

    <section id="content">
        <h2>Our Movies</h2> 
        <ul id="all-movies">

            <?php
                $c=0;
                $i=1;

                $temp = $wp_query;
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                $wp_query->query('post_type=movies' . '&paged=' . $paged . '&posts_per_page=6');

                while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); $c++;

                $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
                $movie_info = $custom["movie_info"][0];

            ?>

            <li id="movie-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                 <?php if (!empty($movie_info)) { echo $movie_info ?>
                 <a class="thickbox" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/movies-modal?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=820&width=610&pid=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">View more info</a>
            </li>

            <?php
                endwhile;
                my_paginate_links();
                $wp_query = null;
                $wp_query = $temp;
                wp_reset_query();
            ?>

        </ul>
    </section>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**My (Failed) Attempt**

What I tried to do was create a separate template (below), create a page called "Movies Modal" in the dashboard, and attribute the template to the page. Then, I tried to grab the `POST ID` from the `a.thickbox` link from the template above (`&pid=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>`) so *only* that post's info will show in the modal template below with this line: `$wp_query->query( 'post_type=movies&p=' . $_GET['pid']);`

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Movies (Modal)
*/
?>

<?php get_header('thickbox'); ?>

    <?php
        $c=0;
        $i=1;

        $temp = $wp_query;
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query();
        $wp_query->query( 'post_type=movies&p=' . $_GET['pid']);

        while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); $c++;

        $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
        $movie_info = $custom["movie_info"][0];
        $actor_bio = $custom["actor_bio"][0];
        $actor_info = $custom["actor_info"][0];

    ?>

    <div id="container">
         <?php if (!empty($movie_info)) { echo $movie_info ?>
         <?php if (!empty($actor_bio)) { echo $actor_bio ?>
         <?php if (!empty($actor_info)) { echo $actor_info ?>
    </div>

    <?php
        endwhile; 
        $wp_query = null;
        $wp_query = $temp;
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

All this did, however, was bring up a modal window with the info for all posts and not *just* the info for the post the link is in, like this:

[image: modal window]

I can't figure out how to get the info for *only* the post I clicked on. Can someone please help me out or push me in the right direction?

**Updates**

```
pid is not set\ngettype: NULLpid intval: 0Array
(
    [post] => post
    [page] => page
    [attachment] => attachment
    [revision] => revision
    [nav_menu_item] => nav_menu_item
    [product] => product
    [product_variation] => product_variation
    [shop_order] => shop_order
    [shop_coupon] => shop_coupon
    [wpcf7_contact_form] => wpcf7_contact_form
    [movies] => movies
    [psdtv] => psdtv
)
Wordpress version: 3.5
```

Changed this block:

```
<li id="movie-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <?php if (!empty($movie_info)) { echo '<span>Summary: '. $movie_info .'</span>'; } ?>
    <a class="thickbox" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/movies-modal/?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=820&width=610&pid=<?php the_ID(); ?>">View more info</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear your use of Thickbox is the culprit. When opening a thickbox via the anchor, the thickbox parameters must always be last, else the other parameters will be removed, e.g. your movies Post ID

http://devll.wordpress.com/2009/10/01/jquery-iframe-thickbox-removes-parameter/

Firstly, your use of queries is incorrect, what's more you never tell your query which post to look for.

Instead you should do a proper query, e.g.:

```
$movie_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'movies',
    'p' => $_GET['pid']
));
if($movie_query->have_posts()){
    while ( $movie_query->have_posts() ) {
        $movie_query->the_post();

    $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    $movie_info = $custom["movie_info"][0];
    $actor_bio = $custom["actor_bio"][0];
    $actor_info = $custom["actor_info"][0];

?>

<div id="container">
     <?php if (!empty($movie_info)) { echo $movie_info ?>
     <?php if (!empty($actor_bio)) { echo $actor_bio ?>
     <?php if (!empty($actor_info)) { echo $actor_info ?>
</div>

<?php
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Before you continue, you will need a grasp of how to do a basic query cleanly, and why and when to use it. For this I give you the following:

- Never modify the main query directly. ( the only time to modify it is when it's passed into a `pre_get_posts` filter )
- Avoid `query_posts`
- Read this quick presentation by [Andrew Nacin, You don't know Query](http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012), it will tell you what to use, how to use it, and why. It is considered by many **necessary** reading.

edit:

Please paste the following snippet above my modified version of your query:

```
echo '<pre>';
if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    echo 'pid is set\n';
} else {
    echo 'pid is not set\n';
}
echo 'gettype: '. gettype($_GET['pid']);
echo 'pid intval: '.intval($_GET['pid']);
$post_types=get_post_types();
print_r($post_types);
echo 'Wordpress version: '.get_bloginfo('version');
echo '</pre>';
```

edit:

This code in your main listing is broken:

```
        <li id="movie-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
             <?php if (!empty($movie_info)) { echo $movie_info ?>
             <a class="thickbox" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/movies-modal?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=820&width=610&pid=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">View more info</a>
        </li>
```

You never added a closing bracket for the if statement or a semi colon. I suggest you also replaced `echo $post->ID;` with `the_ID();` and verify it is indeed printing the correct ID. I'd also suggest putting a '/' between the ?`KeepThis` and the `movies-model`

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I am reading through that now. I tried your code (in the modal template); however I am still met with the same outcome. All posts show in the modal window instead of just the one I queried for. Is there more to the code that needs to be added?

Comment: I've copy pasted a snippet of code that should reveal some important information, if you could place it after get_header and report back what the results are

Comment: Hey Tom, I posted it in the original post. Thanks.

Comment: There you go, pid is not set, that's the source of your problem. btw you're aware that your first code block in your question would generate a 500 error? You've got an if statement that you never close, and a function call with a missing semicolon

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: I made the changes (can you make sure I changed it correctly?) and verified that `the_ID();` is printing the correct ID. However, still no luck with only pulling up the info from one post. I updated my post. Also, it still says the `pid` is not set in the modal pop up.

Comment: and if you manually go there making sure that the get var is set?

Comment: Also can I ask why you used a page called movies-modal rather than just using the single-movies.php template and the posts full URL?

Comment: Also try changing it to movie_id instead of pid, pid is a very vague name and may even be reserved for certain things

Comment: I believe I have found the problem, see the beginning of my answer, it's regarding thickbox and the order you listed the parameters in

Comment: YES!! That was it! Thank you so much! And I didn't even think of using the single-movies.php template. I suppose that would be better. Thank you for that as well.

Comment: Oh, also when I changed my method of querying, the pagination stopped working. I know this is a new question so I opened it here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81480/pagination-doesnt-show-up-for-custom-post-type#comment109757_81480 If you know of a fix, please let me know. Thank you again!