# pagination doesn't show up for custom post type

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Another user on here suggested that my use of queries was incorrect so I'm changing the code. However, the pagination in the first block of code (below) isn't showing up in the HTML while the second one (my original) shows up fine.

This one doesn't work (new code):

```
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    $loop = new WP_Query( array(
                        'post_type' => 'movies',
                        'paged' => $paged,
                        'posts_per_page' => 6
                    ));

                    if($loop->have_posts()){
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                            $loop->the_post();

                            << LOOP GOES HERE >>


                   <?php
                      }
                   }
                   my_paginate_links();
                   wp_reset_postdata();
                   ?>
```

This one works (my original code):

```
                    $c=0;
                    $i=1;

                    $temp = $wp_query;
                    $wp_query = null;
                    $wp_query = new WP_Query();
                    $wp_query->query('post_type=movies' . '&paged=' . $paged . '&posts_per_page=6');

                    while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); $c++;


                 << LOOP GOES HERE >>

                <?php
                    endwhile; 
                    my_paginate_links();
                    $wp_query = null;
                    $wp_query = $temp;
                    wp_reset_query();
                ?>
```

How can I get pagination to show up in the first block of code?

Comment: For getting the paged parameter use this `<?php  $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;  ?>`

Comment: I replaced the line but the pagination still doesn't show, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you considered using a custom post type archive instead of reinventing the wheel and building your own? ( e.g. above )

Comment: Also +1 on the much improved use of WP_Query from your recent question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81475/get-post-info-inside-modal-window/81478#comment109780_81478 You're on the right track =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than attempt to fix your query, I recommend you sidestep it entirely by using custom post type archives!

With permalinks on, you should be able to view a list of all your movies posts by going to:

```
example.com/movies
```

Then, in your theme, create `archive-movies.php`, and it will be used instead of the `archive.php/index.php` for movies archives. Make sure to use the default loop not a custom loop, and WordPress will take care of the post type and pagination in your query.

To control how many posts are displayed on this archive, you can do a filter on `pre_get_posts` to modify the main query before it happens.

```
function john_movies_pagesize( $query ) {
    // exit out if it's the admin or it isn't the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    // so its not admin, and its the main query, is it the movies post archive?
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'movies' ) ) {
        // it is!! Set the posts_per_page to 6
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'john_movies_pagesize', 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom. This seems like a more efficient method. By the way, do you know what may be wrong with the original question just for my future reference? Thanks again!

Comment: your pagination function ( which we cant see so I can only speculate ) is probably calling the default function calls, which refer to the main query ( `$wp_query` ) not your custom query, and so will generate incorrect page numbers and counts

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of how to use paged pagination with custom post types:

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'newsfeed', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged );
$newsquery = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $newsquery->have_posts() ) :
while ( $newsquery->have_posts() ) : $newsquery->the_post();

the_excerpt(); //query here

global $newsquery; $total_pages = $newsquery->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) {
$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
'format' => '?paged=%#%',
'prev_text' => __(' Prev'),
'next_text' => __('Next '),
'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
'total' => $newsquery->max_num_pages
) );

}
endif; wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?