# Order Custom Post Type Archive by multiple values in functions.php

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I saw this post and the function helped to fix my pagination problem for the archives pages for my custom post type: [pagination doesn't show up for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/81480/pagination-doesnt-show-up-for-custom-post-type)

The challenge I have is I need this same type of function to account for ordering the archive in ASC order and by a custom field value which is tied to a DATE value I created.

How to write the function by grabbing code from other places and trial and error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you consulted [the Codex `WP_Query()` entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)?

To query by custom field, you'll need to add [tax query parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to your query args.

e.g.

```
'meta_key' => 'foobar'
```

To sort, you'll need to add [sort and orderby query parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) to your query args.

e.g.

```
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'meta_val_num'
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it seems to break the pagination on the archive page.

Comment: Here's the function I'm using
/*CUSTOM ARCHIVE FOR EVENTS*/
function events_pagesize( $query ) {
    // exit out if it's the admin or it isn't the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    // so its not admin, and its the main query, is it the tr-events post archive?
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tr-events' ) ) {
        // it is!! Set the posts_per_page to 6
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
        $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'events_pagesize', 1 );

I'm trying to order by meta_val

Comment: Please add code to your **original question**, for clarity/syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 0):

<sup><sub>pulled from OP's edit to the question</sub></sup>

RESOLVED... SORT OF

I added these other $query->set parameters and it seems to work for the archive listing

```
/*CUSTOM ARCHIVE FOR EVENTS*/
function events_pagesize( $query ) {
    // exit out if it's the admin or it isn't the main query
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;
    // so its not admin, and its the main query, is it the tr-events post archive?
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'tr-events' ) ) {
        // it is!! Set the posts_per_page to 6
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 4 );
        $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'wpcf-tr-order-date');
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value');
        return;
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'events_pagesize', 1 );
```

While not ideal, for other page templates, this works for the Custom Post Type Archive page.